# C# PdfImage LibTiff iTextSharp G3 / G4 compression

Tags: c#, pdf, compression, itext

I have a service that takes a pdf document, resizes all the images, and replaces it in the pdf. The problem that I'm getting at, is the compression.

Some documents are scanned and saved with a Compression.CCITTFAX3 compression and some are saved with a Compression.CCITTFAX4 compression. I am using iTextSharp and convert the stream bytes to a Tiff, otherwise the image becomes funky because of stride or something.

Below is the code I'm currently making use of to check for the correct filter, and then convert to tiff image.

```
                if (filter == "/CCITTFaxDecode")
                {
                    byte[] data = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)stream);
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (Tiff myTiff = Tiff.ClientOpen("in-memory", "w", ms, new TiffStream()))
                        {
                            myTiff.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, UInt32.Parse(dict.Get(PdfName.WIDTH).ToString()));
                            myTiff.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, UInt32.Parse(dict.Get(PdfName.HEIGHT).ToString()));
                            myTiff.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.CCITTFAX3);
                            myTiff.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, UInt32.Parse(dict.Get(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT).ToString()));
                            myTiff.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
                            myTiff.WriteRawStrip(0, data, data.Length);
                            myTiff.Flush();

                            using (System.Drawing.Image img = new Bitmap(ms))
                            {
                                if (img == null) continue;

                                ReduceResolution(stream, img, quality);
                            }

                            myTiff.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Just to make sure that you understand my question...

I want to find out how I know when to use G3 compression and when to use G4 compression.

Keep in mind that I've tried every code sample I could find.

This is quite important, as we interface with banking systems, and the files uploaded are sent to them as FICA documents.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the replies above. The solution from Mihai seems viable if you do have all the information from the stream. I found that iTextSharp does not do this properly, so I ended up buying pdf4net. Much simpler than trying to figure out whats the better solution, besides, it ended up cheaper than my time I spent on this.

OnceUponATime.... Thank you for the information given above.

PDF4Net has a built in method that you get all the images per page... This sorted my issues, whereas I tried to do this myself using iTextSharp and the examples that were given to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go low level and inspect the image dictionary. The /DecodeParms entry is a dictionary that contains several keys related to CCITT compression. The /K key specifies the compression type: -1 is G4, 0 is G3 1D and 1 is G3 2D.

Update: to be more exact a negative value, usually -1, is G4, 0 is G3 1D and a positive value, usually 1, is G3 2D. To answer your question in the comment, the /K entry is optional and if it is missing the default value is considered to be 0.

Comment: The problem that I have is that when I run this code, 

PdfDictionary Params =(PdfDictionary)dict.Get(PdfName.DECODEPARMS);

my Params.Keys has Columns and Rows, and nothing else. So, effectively when trying to get the PdfName.K, it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise inserting the data direct. I base this assertion on many years of practical experience of PDFs and TIFF in products like ABCpdf .NET (on which I work).

While in theory you should be able to move the data over direct, minor differences between the formats of the compressed data are likely to lead to occasional mismatches.

The fact that some Fax TIFFs contain data which will display correctly in a TIFF viewer but not in a PDF one leads me to suspect that the same kind of problem is likely to operate in the other direction too.

I'm not going to say this kind of problem is common but it is the kind of thing I wouldn't rely on if I was in a bank. Unless you are very sure your data source will be uniform I would suggest it is much safer to decompress and recompress.

I would also note that sometimes images are held inline in the content stream rather than in a separate XObject. Again this is something you will need to cope with unless your data source produces a standard format which you can be sure will not contain this kind of structure.